# Delay component's html angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to do a such thing. When the component load then after 1 seconds to load it's html.
This is code component (ts).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'pagination',
   templateUrl: './app/html/pagination.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/css/pagination.component.css']
})

export class Pagination {}
```

We see in the code `templateUrl: './app/html/pagination.component.html',`How it to load after 1 seconds? 
In general my idea comprises in show a loading with delay(1 sec) for users while execution post request on server.
Have anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use ngIf directive.

So it will look something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="showContent">Will appear after ~1 sec</div>
```

in component code:

```
export class Pagination {
    public showContent: boolean = false;
    public ngOnInit() {
      setTimeout(()=>this.showContent=true, 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is to show component only after a request finished, to achieve this simply subscribe to your request and set a flag to show the component in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="loaded">
...
...
...
</div>
```

In the component's class:

```
@Component....
export class FooComponent{
    let loaded = false;
}
```

And on your request:

```
this.http.post(.....).subscribe(() => {
    this.loaded = true;
});
```

more informations on [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer. SetTimeout is unreliable as the speed of the user's network connection is not always the same.